# Delete all empty cells in a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have an array of cells in which I want to select 3 lines so I used this `temp = testresults(13:15,1:end)`.

The array being bigger, I get a lot of empty cells

```
{'Summary Test Re…'}    {'Overall'   }    {0×0 char          }    {'OVP Transition …'}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}
{'Pass/Fail'       }    {'Passed'    }    {'No Transition t…'}    {'Passed'          }    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}
{'Failed cases'    }    {'No failure'}    {0×0 char          }    {'No failure'      }    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}
```

Hence, I'm trying to remove the empty cells using `temp(~cellfun('isempty',temp))` but, if all the empty cells are gone, it puts all my data in one column:

```
{'Summary Test Results'          }
{'Pass/Fail'                     }
{'Failed cases'                  }
{'Overall'                       }
{'Passed'                        }
{'No failure'                    }
{'No Transition time change'     }
{'OVP Transition level pass/fail'}
{'Passed'                        }
{'No failure'                    }
```

I've tried some variation of the function and I have also tried with `cat(2, temp{:})` but I don't know how to keep the data in the right position.

How can I remove the empty cells without touching the position of the rest of the data?

Comment: You want to "remove the empty cells" from a 2D array, but what goes in their place, or how do you want to rearrange the remaining cells?
E.g you have a 3x2 array with 6 cells, you remove cell (1,2) leaving 5 cells, how do you want to arrange those 5 cells, or what do you want to replace cell (1,2) with?

Comment: @Justin mh good point. So I just want to remove the empty cells at the right of my data if that makes sense. I don't know how to get the last element of the 1st row of my array without going through a for loop

Comment: So you maybe want to remove columns of empty cells, and rows of empty cells?

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes exactly

Comment: @CrisLuengo alright thanks formaking the idea emerge haha I know how to solve my problem !

Comment: Indeed, I guess I didn't need to write that answer. :)

Comment: If you do as @CrisLuengo says then you'll still have empty cells? It sounds to me like perhaps you want an array of rows, and each row can have a different number of elements (in your example 3 non-empty elements in the 1st row, 4 in the 2nd row, and 3 in the 3rd row?). Which would mean you want a ragged array output?

Comment: @Justin yes I did not explain very clearly my problem I guessed but yeah I just want to remove the empty cells around my data not inside if that makes any sense. So just all the empty rows and empty columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a cell array like this one:

```matlab
temp = {
'Summary Test Re…', 'Overall',    '', '',                 'OVP Transition …', '', '', '', ''
'Pass/Fail',        'Passed',     '', 'No Transition t…', 'Passed',           '', '', '', ''
'Failed cases',     'No failure', '', '',                 'No failure',       '', '', '', ''
'',                 '',           '', '',                 '',                 '', '', '', ''};
```

we can find empty cells (as you already found out) using

```matlab
empty = cellfun('isempty',temp);
```

Next, we can delete rows where all cells are empty with

```matlab
temp(all(empty,2),:) = [];
```

and columns where all cells are empty with

```matlab
temp(:,all(empty,1)) = [];
```

`all(empty,1)` returns a logical row vector where an element is `true` if all cells in that column are empty. We use this logical vector to index those array elements and set them to the empty array. Assigning an empty array is MATLAB speak for deleting the array element. Deleting complete rows and columns allows to preserve the array shape.

Note the difference between `temp(:,1)=[]` and `temp{:,1}=[]`. The first one deletes a column of array elements, the second one assigns an empty array to each of the cells in a column of the cell array.

Comment: Thank you very much that is exactly what I was looking for!